# Django saving data in mysql in improper format

Tags: python, django

I am scraping the website and saving data in djnago model.

I have this line

`item.title = site.select('dl/dd/h2/a').select("string()").extract()`

but data is saved in this format

`[u'Master Developer']`

How can i fix that so that only master Developer gets saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you intend to do this...

```
In [35]: l = [u'Master Developer']

In [36]: str(l[0])
Out[36]: 'Master Developer'
```

or

```
In [37]: l[0].encode('utf-8')
Out[37]: 'Master Developer'
```

Comment: thanks both are ok. why can i use str(l) whats the use of l[0]

Comment: @user15: `l` is a `list`, you want to access it's `1st` element, hence `l[0]`

Comment: @user15 they both don't do the same thing, keep that in mind. Stick with the second option.